# Bootstrap not switching tab by url

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a form that will allow users to select what email service they want to use.

However when I am using bootstrap, the links reload the page but do not switch the tab that I need it to.

Example

If I load the page, and click the link to "GMail" it reloads the page but stays on the default tab.

Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Email Setup</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/stylesheets/email_setup.css">
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Javascript to enable link to tab
        console.log("ASDF");
var url = document.location.toString();
if (url.match('#')) {
   $('.nav-tabs a[href="#' + url.split('#')[1] + '"]').tab('show');
}

 $('.nav-tabs a').on('shown.bs.tab', function(e) {
    window.location.hash = e.target.hash;
  });

</script>
<body>
<div id="email_setup_table" class="container">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active">
            <a href="#tab-default" data-toggle="tab">Select</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#tab-gmailTab" data-toggle="tab">Gmail</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#tab-yahooTab" data-toggle="tab">Yahoo</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#tab-outlookTab" data-toggle="tab">Outlook</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#tab-otherTab" data-toggle="tab">Other</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab-default">
            <h3>Select Email Provider</h3>
            <a href="/email_bot/front_end/email_setup.html#tab-gmailTab">GMail</a>
            <a href="/email_bot/front_end/email_setup.html#tab-yahooTab">Yahoo</a>
            <a href="/email_bot/front_end/email_setup.html#tab-outlookTab">Outlook</a>
            <a href="/email_bot/front_end/email_setup.html#tab-otherTab">Manual Setup</a>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-gmailTab">
            <h3>Gmail Setup</h3>
            <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp"
                           placeholder="Enter email">
                    <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.
                    </small>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-yahooTab">
            <h3>Yahoo support coming soon</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-outlookTab">
            <h3>Outlook support coming soon</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-otherTab">
            <h3>Other support coming soon</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have no idea why it is not switching automatically and any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are clicking a link, you'll need to prevent the default action of that link if you don't want the page to attempt navigation.

Similar to the [Via JavaScript](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/#via-javascript) Bootstrap example, you should be able to accomplish this with the following JS. Note the `$(function() {` wrapper that is jQuery's [document ready](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) to assure the page elements have finished loading.

```
$(function() {
    $('#tab-default a').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // Don't navigate the page
        $('.nav-tabs a[href="' + this.hash + '"]').tab('show'); // Activate the tab
    });
});
```